# Not able to install jsreport.Embedded

Tags: visual-studio, reporting, nuget-package, jsreport

I was trying to install  jsreport.Embedded using the command "Install-Package jsreport.Embedded" in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2015 community edition.
The installation fails with the following error log:

Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1' with respect to project 'Temple Billing', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1'
Adding package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\TB\packages'
Added package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\TB\packages'
Added package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file 'C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\TB\packages\jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1\tools\install.ps1'
Copy  C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\TB\packages\jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1\tools\jsreport\install.cmd  to  C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\TB\jsreport
Running  C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\TB\jsreport\install.cmd
install.cmd : module.js:328
At C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\TB\packages\jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1\tools\install.ps1:138 char:3
+   & $installPath
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (module.js:328:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

```
throw err;
^
```

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\packages\jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1\tools\install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:980:3

Install failed. Rolling back...
Removed package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1 : jsreport.Client [1.0.0, ), Microsoft.Bcl.Async [1.0.168, ), Newtonsoft.Json [9.0.1, ), Node.js [5.3.0, ), Npm [3.5.2, )' from 'packages.config'
Removing package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1 : jsreport.Client [1.0.0, ), Microsoft.Bcl.Async [1.0.168, ), Newtonsoft.Json [9.0.1, ), Node.js [5.3.0, ), Npm [3.5.2, )' from folder 'C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\TB\packages'
Removed package 'jsreport.Embedded.1.0.1 : jsreport.Client [1.0.0, ), Microsoft.Bcl.Async [1.0.168, ), Newtonsoft.Json [9.0.1, ), Node.js [5.3.0, ), Npm [3.5.2, )' from folder 'C:\Users\usr\OneDrive\TB\packages'
Install-Package : Failed to install jsreport from npm, check install-log.txt for details
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package jsreport.Embedded
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

The install-log.txt file is empty.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: I cannot replicate this. To what project type are you installing this nuget package? Do you have x64 windows? Are you able to install Node.js.5.3.0, Npm 3.5.2 and jsreport.Client 1.0.0 separately?

Comment: Thank you very much for checking out this issue. Mine is a Windows Forms project. I have x64 Windows. I was able to install Node.js.5.3.0, Npm 3.5.2 and jsreport.Client 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsreport.Embedded nuget currently expect to be installed into the project which is inside solution directory. Please select "Create directory for solution" in the new project wizard.

[image: create project]

Bug reference https://github.com/jsreport/net/issues/19

Comment: I see you are new to SO... please mark the answer as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.